# Insert row number as a column in datatable/dataset

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, dataset

My datatable/dataset doesn't contain a row number column. How can i via code enter a column as "Row No" that could tell me the row number entered.

Say Currently my dataset is

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3
ABC    TIGER  USA 
DEF    LION   UK 
GHI    HORSE  UAE
```

Hence i wish to have as

Row No 
1 
2 
3

how can i do that?

Comment: 124 questions: just 13 upvotes cast. not a great incentive; plus its a very poor question.

Comment: @Xor - How are you creating or populating the DataSet/DataTable?  Are you creating the DataTable programatically, or filling it from other source?

Answer (score 2):

in case of datatable/dataset i think you don't need row no bc every row in datatable holds the index you can get it by index no. in case you are about the use that column in binding anywhere then 
while getting table from database you can add row no. e.g.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER (ORDER BY EmployeeName) AS Row, 
    EmployeeId, EmployeeName, Salary 
FROM Employees
```

and if you want to add rowno in code behind that just loop thru you tables rows and add new column and set the values of index+1

Answer (score 1):

Logically speaking, you can add the column to the select statement, or you can add the column in the app. If I couldn't add the row number in the select (not automatic in all DBs), I might add the column in the select:

Select 0 row_no, col1, col2, col2 from mytable

and populate the row_no column in the app:

int i = 0;
foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows) r["row_no"] = i++;